# Hide file from people using a browser but have it visible for AJAX within the site

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php file that get the content from using AJAX from another page. It am trying to keep the contents secret until I reveal it. Is there a way to hide a php file from someone putting it's URL into a browser, while still making it available to the AJAX call.

I have tried Deny on .htaccess, but that stops it being available via the AJAX call.

Comment: No. You need some way of securely letting the server know that it may reveal the file when next requested. You didn't say what the criteria are which make it possible to reveal the file

Comment: I am using jQuery AJAX to get the clients of the file when the PHP page loads. The php file to be included uses sleep() to delay it being displayed.

Comment: Ok. So it's not really secret at all then, merely delayed. Is there something which restricts who can access the PHP page? Basically you need some sort of authorisation so the server can be sure whether it should serve the file to any given incoming request, or not. Whether that's an Ajax request or not is largely irrelevant - PHP has no reliable way of knowing what triggered a request

Comment: P.s. a better architecture would be to set a timer in the JavaScript to delay sending the Ajax request, rather than hog your server resources by sleeping the PHP - that just takes up server threads which could be serving other requests instead

Comment: Thanks. I tried the put the delay into the JavaScript, but I couldn't get the AJAX to work within the setTimeout (). Not sure why. I'll post the code tomorrow.

Comment: Your suggestion about authorisation sounds like the solution. What should I look up to do that?

Comment: Your suggestion about authorisation sounds like the solution. What should I look up to do that?

Comment: There are many ways, in theory. Again it depends a bit on what the specifics of the scenario are, which you haven't explained